# Palette using with Glide sometimes fail to load dark vibrant color

Tags: android, palette, android-glide

I am using **palette-v7:23.2.1** with **glide:3.7.0** like mentioned below, but sometimes the **dark** vibrant color is not successfully extracted and I get the default color instead.

After I clear the glide's cache and try it with the same image again, I get the right color. The strange is, that light vibrant color is always extracted, but the dark one not.

What could be the problem and how to solve it?

---

In onCreateView():

```java
Glide.with(mContext)
    .load(artworkUrl)
    .asBitmap()
    .into(new BitmapImageViewTarget(mArtworkInToolbar) {
        @Override
        public void onResourceReady(Bitmap bitmap, GlideAnimation anim) {
            new Palette.Builder(bitmap).generate(paletteAsyncListener);
            super.onResourceReady(bitmap, anim);
        }
    });
```

Listener:

```java
public final Palette.PaletteAsyncListener paletteAsyncListener =
    new Palette.PaletteAsyncListener() {

    @Override
    public void onGenerated(Palette palette) {
        if (palette == null) return;

        int default = ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.colorPrimary);
        int color = palette.getVibrantColor(default); //always ok
        int colorDark = palette.getDarkVibrantColor(default); //not always

        // --- Setting the color --
    }
};
```

Comment: https://github.com/bumptech/glide/wiki/Custom-targets#overriding-default-behavior   this link gives the reason for this problem and solution

Comment: The first solution, that I've used is not recommended, because the second async call could update wrong ViewHolder, but it's not my case. I've also tried the second example, but sometimes it won't extract second color, or first in the same scenario and same image.

Answer (score 1):

```
***Here this is worked for me*** 
make a class name PaletteBitmap.java

public class PaletteBitmap {
    public final Palette palette;
    public final Bitmap bitmap;

    public PaletteBitmap(@NonNull Bitmap bitmap, @NonNull Palette palette) {
        this.bitmap = bitmap;
        this.palette = palette;
    }
    Bitmap getBitmap()
    {
        return bitmap;
    }
}
class PaletteBitmapResource implements Resource<PaletteBitmap> {
    private final PaletteBitmap paletteBitmap;
    private final BitmapPool bitmapPool;

    public PaletteBitmapResource(@NonNull PaletteBitmap paletteBitmap, @NonNull BitmapPool bitmapPool) {
        this.paletteBitmap = paletteBitmap;
        this.bitmapPool = bitmapPool;
    }

    @Override public PaletteBitmap get() {
        return paletteBitmap;
    }

    @Override public int getSize() {
        return Util.getBitmapByteSize(paletteBitmap.bitmap);
    }

    @Override public void recycle() {
        if (!bitmapPool.put(paletteBitmap.bitmap)) {
            paletteBitmap.bitmap.recycle();
        }
    }
}
class PaletteBitmapTranscoder implements ResourceTranscoder<Bitmap,  PaletteBitmap> {
    private final BitmapPool bitmapPool;

    public PaletteBitmapTranscoder(@NonNull Context context) {
        this.bitmapPool = Glide.get(context).getBitmapPool();
    }

    @Override public Resource<PaletteBitmap> transcode(Resource<Bitmap> toTranscode) {
        Bitmap bitmap = toTranscode.get();
        Palette palette = new Palette.Builder(bitmap).generate();
        PaletteBitmap result = new PaletteBitmap(bitmap, palette);
        return new PaletteBitmapResource(result, bitmapPool);
    }

    @Override public String getId() {
        return PaletteBitmapTranscoder.class.getName();
    }
}


**Now in Your onCreateView() do like this**
Glide.with(this).fromUri().asBitmap()
                .transcode(new  PaletteBitmapTranscoder(this),PaletteBitmap.class)
                .fitCenter()load(uri).into(new  ImageViewTarget<PaletteBitmap>(imageView){

        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
        @Override
        protected void setResource(PaletteBitmap resource) {
            imageView.setImageBitmap(resource.getBitmap());
            int colorP =  resource.palette.getMutedColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorPrimary));
        int   colorD=resource.palette.getDarkMutedColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color .colorPrimaryDark));
           // dowhatever you want
        }
    });;
```

Comment: Basically the same solution as [link](https://github.com/florent37/GlidePalette). I've tried it too. I know, that extracting could failed with certains pictures, but sometimes it fails with the same picture. That's the question. But thank's for the complete solution.